# How can i make this low poly edges smooth without bevel?

Tags: modeling, texturing, edit-mode, game-engine, bevel

[image]
this is a low-poly mesh I want to make smooth edges like high poly mesh without beveling them

Comment: you need to bake the details from a high poly mesh

Comment: You can't make round edges without bevelling

Comment: Well, you could use the _Bevel_  shader in Cycles, but that's a trick that's unlikely to be exportable